# Get multiple Elements on one level ImmutableJS

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have an object looking like

```
const foo = Immutable.fromJS(
    {
        90234:
        {
            bar: 'a'
            metaData: { },
            comment: 'abc',
            photos: [1,2,3,4,5]
        }
    }
)
```

How do I get `comments`  and `photos`  in one line with 'ImmutableJS'.

```
foo.get('90234')....?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As immutable types box their contents, you cannot "return" back two different contents, however you can map over the keys like so -

```
foo.get('90234')
   .values()
   .map((value, key)=> key=="comments"?doSomething(value): (key=="photos")?doSomethingElse(value):"")
```

Another possibility is to return a new object containing only "comments" and "photos", like so -

```
let subSet = foo.get('90234').reduce(
    (accumulator, value, key)=>{
        if (key == "photos" || key == "comments"){
            return accumulator.set(key, value);
        }
        return accumulator;
    },
    new Map()
)
```